# Django model id not changing through for loop

Tags: python, django

So I have a for loop in my Django template that loops through a product in my products model. The product model has an `amount` attribute that is supposed to change when the user clicks on the 'add' button. I have made a hidden form that launches the upvote method which takes a request and a `pk` and increases the amount attribute by 1.

The problem is that when I click on the add button, only two of the products' amount increase. I can't get the rest of the products' amount attribute to increases.

---

Here's the Django template code:

```
<div class="card-deck d-flex justify-content-start container-fluid">
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="card lead m-3" style="min-width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ product.product_id }}</h6>
          <hr>
        <p class="card-text">
            Expiration date: {{ product.expiration_date }}
        </p>
        <p class="card-text">
            amount: {{ product.amount }} <a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote').submit();}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">+</button></a>
        </p>

        <p class="card-text">
            tags:
        {% for t in product.tag.all %}
            <span class="badge badge-primary">{{ t.name }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form action="{% url 'upvote' pid=product.id %}" method="POST" id="upvote">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden">
    </form>
```

here's the upvote method in the views.py file:

```
def upvote(request, pid):
if request.method == "POST":
    product = get_object_or_404(models.Product, pk=pid)
    product.amount += 1
    product.save()
return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You end up having multiple elements with the same `id` (`upvote`) which is not allowed, and the Javascript code always uses the first `form` element it finds and submits that one.

To have unique form ids, change the following line

```
<form action="{% url 'upvote' pid=product.id %}" method="POST" id="upvote">
```

to

```
<form action="{% url 'upvote' pid=product.id %}" method="POST" id="upvote_{{ product.id }}">
```

and the following line

```
<a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote').submit();}">
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:{document.getElementById('upvote_{{ product.id }}').submit();}">
```